# Snap scroll overscrolling on Chrome

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am applying `snap-scroll` to the HTML of my website, and for some reason it is either skipping elements or snapping to places it should not. This problem becomes worse on smaller screens, and it seems to work fine on Edge so I am not sure what the problem is. Any help would be great, thanks.

HTML

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="snap-div"></div>
        <div class="snap-div"></div>
        <div class="snap-div"></div>
        <div class="snap-div"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```css
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    scroll-snap-type: y;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    scroll-padding-top: 5em;
    scroll-padding-bottom: 5em;
    scroll-snap-stop: always;
}

.snap-div {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```